# Helping me understand these computation time

Tags: c, performance, opencv

I am doing several matrix computations on OpenCV and I cannot understand why it takes the time it takes

Operation 1 is : multiplication of a 320x1 column vector by a 390x320 matrix, then multiplication by a 72000x390 matrix. Time : ~35 ms.
Operation 1b is : 10 times the multiplication of a 32x1 column vector by a 390x32 matrix, then multiplication by a 7200x390 matrix. Time : ~35 ms

Operation 2 is: multiplication of a 320x1 column vector by a 72000x320 matrix. Time : ~30 ms.
Operation 2b is : 10 times the multiplication of a 32x1 column vector by a 7200x32 matrix. Time : ~10 ms

Basically in Operations 1 I am always using an intermediate column vector of size 390, while I skip this in Operations 2. Yet I cannot explain why the operation 2b is much faster than 2, when 1b and 1 are the same speed.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Did you ever question the validity and accuracy of the method you use to come up with these millisecond figures? Proper profiling can be tricky and somewhat of an art. E.g. cache effects can lead to interesting numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure how cache effects work but the results are reproductible and I have the same numbers by averaging severa times the same operations or doing them in another order etc

Comment: Cache effects include speedups through locality of reference. If a 2d matrix is accessed element by element, execution time depends critically on memory reads in row/column or column/row order. I suggest you use a real profiler to instrument your code instead of a global timing of execution time. This likely provides detailed insight into what is going on under the hood. Many C compilers allow to do this with the `-pg` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the number of multiplications to be performed by each operation, I see:

```
Operation 1: 390 * 320 = 124,800
Operation 1b: 10 *390 * 32 = 124,800
Operation 2: 72000 * 320 = 23,040,000
Operation 2b: 10 * 7200 * 32 = 2,304,000
```

Operation 1 and 1b require the same amount of multiplication, but Operation 2 requires 10X the multiplication of Operation 2b.

Comment: I am not sure about the formula you are using to count the number of multiplications... multiplying a NxM matrix with a Mx1 vector accounts for NxM multiplications for me, is it what you are using?

Comment: You are correct, but operation 2 is still 10X operation 2b:
10 * 7200 * 32 < 72000 * 320